# clarification in jboss 5.1 jms configuration

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss5.x, jboss-messaging

I am configuring connection factory and queue in jboss 5.1.I googled and got some info on that, every where it is suggested that connection factory and queue should be configured in connection-factories-service
and destinations-service.
I want to know what is the use of jms-ds.xml file,what configuration and when we need to specify here.

`jms-ds.xml`: `JMSProviderLoader` and `JmsXA` inflow resource adaptor connection factory binding configuration

i am not able to understand what is inflow resource adaptor connection binding
Please explain with example.

Answer (score 0):

`jms-ds.xml` is for your resource adapter configuration.  This is where you would set up connections that your MDBs would end up using.

Comment: I have two applications one is sending messages to queue and another application that is consuming those application but deployed on same AS.In this case if i am deploying first application that means which only sends messages in that case no configuration is required in jms-ds.xml file but if i am deploying MDB's then only it would require setting right? If i am right configuration in jms-ds.xml is required only for inbound communication not for outbound communication.

Comment: jms-ds.xml can list out all destinations and connection factories as well.  It does have a role in the outbound messaging, but primarily is used for inbound messaging.

Comment: actually what is happening when i am configuring connection factory and queue in jboss 5.1 in default/deploy/messagging/connection-factories-service,destinations-service.xml respectively then on start up it was givng lots of error.
but when i configured same thing from admin console it created files in deploy folder only.
is this the way it does or it is some defect in jboss 5.1?